# Как включить элементы управления на карте MapKit 3.0 for Android?

Tags: yandexmapkit

Подскажите,не нахожу в документации к MapKit 3.0 for Android mapcontroller...как включит кнопки зум, поиск, фулскрин и т.д.?

Answer (score 4):

Задал данный вопрос в службу поддержки yandex. Ответ следующий:

"Встроенных элементов управления нет, но можно добавить свои на View карты.

Методы для изменения масштаба есть:
Move https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/map/Map-docpage/#method_detail__method_move__CameraPosition__Animation__CameraCallback
и
CameraPosition https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/map/CameraPosition-docpage/ .

Аналогично для iOS:
https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/ios/mapkit/ref/YMKMap-docpage/#method_detail__method_moveWithCameraPosition_animationType_cameraCallback__nonnullYMKCameraPosition_pointer__nonnullYMKAnimation_pointer__nullableYMKMapCameraCallback
и
https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/ios/mapkit/ref/YMKCameraPosition-docpage/"