# Добавление кнопок Yandex Map Kit в Android на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, yandexmapkit

Нигде в интернете не нашел инфы про то, как добавить кнопки масштаба и кнопку текущего местоположения в карте от Yandex Map kit. Все советы устаревшие.
Единственное, что я понял, что нет больше уже готовых элементов управлений, есть только методы. Так вот, где эти методы достать?

Comment: Вот такой же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828739/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-mapkit-3-0-for-android